# Validez del término "Inmessionante"

Tags: vocabulario, definiciones, rae

**Background:**

El año pasado leí una noticia sobre la inclusión de una palabra al diccionario *Santillana*. Se trata del término **"Inmessionante"**, el cual fue creado en un intento de definir la manera de jugar al futbol de Lionel Messi.

La noticia completa la pueden leer en [El Mundo Deportivo](http://www.mundodeportivo.com/20130208/fc-barcelona/inmessionante-adjetivo-messi-diccionario-santillana-pepsi_54365205070.html).

En ningún sitio logré encontrar información que verifique la validez de dicha palabra ante la RAE, y me parece curioso que ésta misma se incluyó en el diccionario Santillana impulsado por una campaña de la empresa PEPSI (patrocinadora del futbolista en cuestión).

**Pregunta:**

Al no estar incluido en el diccionario de la RAE, ¿tiene validez oficial dicho término?

Comment: ¿Qué significa que una palabra tenga "valided oficial"?

Comment: @JoulSauron, en otras palabras, es correcto utilizar dicha palabra? Al aparecer en un diccionario como el Santillana, adquiere respaldo suficiente para considerarse como un adjetivo correcto? La verdad ignoro el proceso de adición de nuevas palabras en el diccionario antes mencionado.

Comment: En dos palabras: [im presionante](http://www.antena3.com/asi-es-antena3/celebrities/dos-palabras-impresionante_2010122200143.html).

Comment: Al parecer es una edición limitada del diccionario, claramente con fines publicitarios: http://www.taringa.net/posts/noticias/16361838/Inmessionante-es-aceptada-por-la-R-A-E.html

Comment: A la hora de hablar y usar el termino, no hay reglas, ni nadie quién tenga derecho a impedirte decír lo que te place... por otro lado, sí estás en un campo academico, es importante que hagas un uso correcto del español, para no perder el respeto de tus pares y profesores... y en caso de un trabajo escrito, creo que no hace falta decír, que sí, usar terminos fuera de la lengua, te puede acarrear problemas.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Esa palabra se incluyó como parte de una campaña publicitaria. No tiene validez oficial.

En principio la RAE es la encargada de aceptar palabras y periódicamente agrega palabras de uso común o de nueva creación. Hay palabras o variaciones que se usan comunmente que no estan reconocidas pero sería difícil decir que son incorrectas debido a su uso común.

En cualquier caso esta palabra no creo que se llegue a incluir porque no es de uso habitual, por lo tanto se puede considerar que no es válida.

Comment: Lo que no me queda claro es como puede tratarse de una campaña publicitaria y aparecer en un diccionario como el 'Santillana'. Es decir, cualquiera puede incluir una palabra en el diccionario a su antojo?

Comment: Santillana es una empresa privada, supongo que por razones comerciales y de promoción incluyen lo que sea.

Answer (score 3):

Independientemente de que la RAE acepte una palabra u otra, ya que entre otras cosas muchas de las palabras o acepciones utilizadas por la gente de diferentes sitios pueden no estar reflejadas allí y tener una "*validez*" allí donde se usa; ese "*término*" es parte de una campaña publicitaria. Además, nadie (probablemente en ninguna parte del mundo) usa esa palabra, que al final las personas son las que *hacen* que las palabras lo sean; por lo que se puede decir que no debería ser considerada una palabra como tal.